# ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061], Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.5.2, Windows 10.

I am trying to send an e-mail with python, simplest way possible. I have seen some other posts with the same error but they are trying to create a server. Can't I send an e-mail like that? this is my code:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

msg = MIMEText("Test")
msg['Subject'] = 'A Test Message'
msg['From']='Sender'
msg['To'] = 'Recipient'

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail('Sender', ['Recipient'], msg.as_string())
```

When I replace Sender and Recipient with two existing email addresses, I get the following error:

**ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

Any idea why the error occurs? The error appears to be in s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost') line

(by the way I found this code online it is not mine)

Comment: It means there is no SMTP server running on localhost. Did you expect there to be a server there? If not, what SMTP servers do you have access to?

Comment: This is the only code, if this is what you mean. No, I have not created any servers by myself.

Comment: How much do you understand how email works? You need access to an SMTP server to receive the email and take responsibility for routing that email to the right destination. Depending on your networking setup (at home, on a colocated server, etc.) you may need to provide login credentials or a separate SMTP server that forwards directly to another server, etc. Stack Overflow is not the place to teach you these concepts however.

Comment: so is the code completely wrong? Because, as I said, I found it online and the author said it was working. If it is not completely wrong please tell me how can I fix it

Comment: No, it is code that'd work if you had an SMTP server running on the same machine. So for you it is merely incorrectly configured. Don't assume code found online applies to every situation.

Comment: Can I fix the code somehow so that it can send an email through gmail for example?

Comment: I already gave you directions on what you need to fix it. You need an SMTP server and then configure the code to use that server. How to do that is outside the scope of this site.